# Approximation of a polynomial / LinAlgError: Incompatible dimensions

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I need graphic, but I have error.
My experiance about: To construct polynomials of the first and second degree approximating the results of the experiment using the least squares method. The results are displayed in the form of tables of values and graphs of the obtained polynomials. I need not table :) My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas import DataFrame, Series

x = np.array([1.0, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8, 2.0])
y = np.array([2.0, 6.0, 4.0, 4.0, 2.0, 5.0])

m1 = np.vstack((x, np.ones(len(x)))).T
m2 = np.vstack((x**2, x, np.ones(len(x)))).T

s1 = np.linalg.lstsq(m1, y, rcond = None)[0]
s2 = np.linalg.lstsq(m2, y, rcond = None)[0]

print(s1)
print(np.std(s1))
print(s2)
print(np.std(s2))

m, c = np.linalg.lstsq(m1, y, rcond = None)[0]
m2, c2 = np.linalg.lstsq(m1, s1, rcond = None)[0]
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
plt.plot(x, y, 'o', label='Исходные данные', markersize=10) 
plt.plot(x, m*x + c, 'r', label='Линейная экстраполяция') 
plt. legend()
plt. show()
```

Error:

```
LinAlgError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [58], line 2
      1 m, c = np.linalg.lstsq(m1, y, rcond = None)[0]
----> 2 m, c = np.linalg.lstsq(m1, s1, rcond = None)[0]
      3 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
      4 plt.plot(x, y, 'o', label='Исходные данные', markersize=10) 

File <__array_function__ internals>:180, in lstsq(*args, **kwargs)

File d:\python\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py:2271, in lstsq(a, b, rcond)
   2269 m2, n_rhs = b.shape[-2:]
   2270 if m != m2:
-> 2271     raise LinAlgError('Incompatible dimensions')
   2273 t, result_t = _commonType(a, b)
   2274 result_real_t = _realType(result_t)

LinAlgError: Incompatible dimensions
```

And too mistake

```
from numpy import *
from numpy.random import *
delta = 5.0
s = np.linalg.lstsq(m2, y, rcond = None)[0]
s2 = np.linalg.lstsq(m2, s2, rcond = None)[0]
x_prec = linspace(-7, 7, 101)
plt.plot(x, y, 'D') 
plt.plot(x_prec, s[0] * x_prec**2 + s[1] * x_prec+s[2],'-', lw=2)
plt.plot(x_prec, s2[0] * x_prec**2 + s2[1] * x_prec+s2[2],'-', lw=2)
plt.grid()
```

I am working in jupyter notebook, please help me

Im try working in s1 and s2, it didn't work out :(